# Excel comments function for specific dataset groups

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to show comments of `PROCESSED` and `NOT PROCESSED` from a specific data set. I have some repetitive source names in rows and if even one of the specific group has a `0`, the formula should then show `NOT PROCESSED` message.

Something like below:

| Name | Volume | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 0 | NOT PROCESSED |
| BE | 85 | PROCESSED |
| BE | 87 | PROCESSED |
| CCE | 89 | NOT PROCESSED |
| CCE | 0 | NOT PROCESSED |
| CCE | 78 | NOT PROCESSED |

This means if any one entry in a group like CCE has `0` then I need to show that CCE has `NOT PROCESSED`.

How to do this in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ***Name*** is in columns A and ***Volume*** in column B:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A, A2,B:B,0)>0,"not processed","processed")
```